# Jersey resources produces no output

Tags: java, xml, scala, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I have a resource:

```
 @GET
  @Path("/{v1}")
  @Produces(Array(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML))
  def asyncGet(@Suspended asyncResponse: AsyncResponse, @PathParam("v1") v1: Int): Unit = {...}
```

in its body it asynchronously responds with Result object(`asyncResponse.resume(resultObject)`) which is declared as

```
@XmlRootElement
case class Result(res: Double)
```

In my pom I have next dependencies:

```
javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.0
org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-grizzly2-http:2.13
```

and these are the only dependencies which relates to web or rest.
When I perform request to my reource I get `Internal server error` response(and nothing is logged on the server side), however all goes fine in resource's logic until marshalling paramters.

I suspect that something goes wrong during selection of the marshaller, because when I set resource to respond with string representation of the object(via `toString` method), it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in

```
@XmlRootElement
case class Result(res: Double)
```

JAXB needs no-arg constructor to function properly(and while debugging I get exception indicating that but rest client got exception not related to this issue). So the correct version of this class is

```
    @XmlRootElement
    case class Result(res: Double) {
      def this() = this(0)
    }
```